# DATEADD 30 days from now is excluding one day

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2012

I have a sql query...

When I run this query from today's date I will get records returned from 7/22/2016.

```
SELECT test_id, lat, long
FROM  testDB.src.test_20
WHERE test_date >= DATEADD(day,-32, GETDATE()) and lat is not null and long is not null
```

When I change the DATEADD function to -31, I will get records from 7/23/2016.

```
SELECT test_id, lat, long
FROM  testDB.src.test_20
WHERE test_date >= DATEADD(day,-31, GETDATE()) and lat is not null and long is not null
```

I might not be clearly understanding how the DATEADD function works. What I would think would happen when using -31, is that records from today to minus 31 days ago, including records from 7/22/2016 would be returned (since 31 days ago from today is 7/22/2016).

Why are records from 7/22/2016 not returned when using -31?

SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: `DATEADD(day,-32, GETDATE())` returns timestamp too so `test_date` should have timestamp greater than the current time when you run this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider just that expression on its own:

```
select DATEADD(day,-31, GETDATE())
2016-07-22 16:18:42.697
```

And then you look for rows with `test_date` greater than that date-time.

Perhaps you need to eliminate the time part and only consider days:

```
select DATEADD(day,-31, cast(GETDATE() as date))
2016-07-22
```

and date-times like `2016-07-22 10:15:00.420` will be found.

Answer (score 4):

`GETDATE()` doesn't just include date but comes with the time stamp when you run.

For example

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

returns

> 2016-08-22 10:21:36.867

So, when you add `-31` in `DATEADD(day,-31, GETDATE())`, it compares your `test_date` to be greater than or equal to

> 2016-07-22 10:21:36.867

The more appropriate way to compare just dates is described below:

If you need to be specific about number of days

```
CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day,-31, GETDATE()))
```

which will result in just retrieving date part

> 2016-07-22

If you need to compare by calendar month

```
CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,-1, GETDATE()))
```

So, finally you should be writing your query as

```
SELECT
    test_id,
    lat,
    long
FROM testDB.src.test_20
WHERE test_date >= CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, -31, GETDATE()))
AND lat IS NOT NULL
AND long IS NOT NULL
```

For more information on `GETDATE()`, you can look at [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx).